# Return true if a specific sub collection exists in Firebase/Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know if sub collection `'categories'` is created inside my `users` collection in Firestore and return true if created and false if not

Answer (score 1):

Subcollections are not really created.  They simply appear to exist as soon as a document is first added to it, and they appear to be removed as soon as the last document is deleted.

If you want to know if a subcollection appears to exist, then all you have to do is query it.  If it returns documents, then you know it exists.  You can limit the query to 1 document to be efficient about it.

Comment: Thank you so much, But can you give me the query for it?